# Chrome losing focus while typing on Google pages

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, lost-focus

I've encountered a problem while typing mail or translating somthing on gmail/google translator in Google Chrome. Always when ajax occured - automatic translate/automatic draft save the box into I'm currently typping just lose focus and I need to click into it again. I've already tried install another version of Chrome - current beta release: 29.0.1547.49 beta-m. But nothing changed it's the same as on stable version 28... In another browsers its working correctly. I've not installed any extension in past time and I don't remeber to set up anything in Chrome. I'm running Windows 7 fully upgrated with actual updates.

If anyone is encountering the same problem or know how to solve it, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: This is happening to me in gmail today as well using chrome browser (ubuntu).  What a pain!

Answer (score 0):

This was encountering the problem: http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/ It probably updated itself and new version have this bug.
So I replaced this with Screen capture from Google

Comment: The new version of Webpage Screenshot don't have this bug (v9.9.7/9.9.8). So, you can reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of a bug in Webpage Screenshot. Now it's working well.